# Play store update problem 64 bit processor (32 bit mode)

Tags: android, 32bit-64bit, samsung-mobile, exynos

After google play store 64 bit app requirement, I update abi filter in gradle file.I tested app in a 64 bit smart phone and 
i did not encounter any problems. I upload app play store. After a while, i get some response from samsung smart phone users. They said i am not update app google play store not allow even my phone is new. (Devices samsung sm-a710f and sm-j530f.)

I searched two devices processor. They have 64 bit processor and also have samsung exynos processor. Last things, i found sm-a710f devices and install aida64. I see 64 bit armv8-a (32-bit mode) in processor label.

Summary, Does anyone not update the application with the reason of armv8-a (32-bit mode) ? Or Is there anyone who has experienced this situation?

Thanks.

Comment: This seems a platform related issue, are there any errors that show up? We need more context like code to be able to help.

Comment: Play store only say "No suitable device to install the application."

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are only providing a 64 bit version of the app now. You should both provide a 64bit and a 32bit version of your application, if you want to support all devices.

This will lead to an increased apk size.

Using google android app bundle you can provide users with specialized apks (calculated by google) that only contain dependencies in the architectures the special device needs.